FFMPEG, How to stream video and audio into one file with volume adjustment and video cropping
ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -i "Knockout.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.1,atempo=1.1[a];[1:a]volume=1[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2[audio]" -filter_complex "setpts=PTS/1.1,crop='min(iw\,ih1/1)':'min(ih\,iw1/1)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune fastdecode -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -r 30 -strict experimental -shortest "Output_00001.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -i "Knockout.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.1,atempo=1.1[a];[1:a]volume=1[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2[audio]" -filter_complex "setpts=PTS/1.1,crop='min(iw\,ih1/1)':'min(ih\,iw1/1)" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune fastdecode -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -r 30 -strict experimental -shortest "Output_00001.mp4"
ffmpeg version 2024-12-19-git-494c961379-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 14.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-liblc3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      59. 51.100 / 59. 51.100
libavcodec     61. 27.101 / 61. 27.101
libavformat    61.  9.101 / 61.  9.101
libavdevice    61.  4.100 / 61.  4.100
libavfilter    10.  6.101 / 10.  6.101
libswscale      8. 12.100 /  8. 12.100
libswresample   5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
libpostproc    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
Metadata:
minor_version   : 512
major_brand     : isom
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
metadata1       : TC1nO7kRGA2g5D7EvY6mVieKMGAICBrUodQ2askGrBS9jYT4Vj3PxKPaPJbSJiYW312zpE9OA+GfQsSmsg/l0YPpVbGHSS0k1WWlIhavn4vgaEjIiMMw5ES5FyQ6NBpt9K1YOSiIg6IEc4CgvXCVgyI5VVvX9u053QTky2KsdRNRA32Ui1XkoBTAB
metadata0       : ChtzZWN1cml0eS5rbGluZy5tZXRhX2VuY3J5cHQS8AGDblTacnE/fscfVL6m9on8gh3O9gP57LnH5Gi3m5WuoRauKnAkpgZgCqmDNvDCKcv7WjIn6u+WSNAu60xW9WLkiOodDgOO2LkcD3RQmNE435FJW7rzQGPQCWEORRjI73eTSQLHggb3O876An7Ho7eHOiOljlsdEkvPDRIGlAwfn5QZKj43rdvl4q6p0lL1Wjb6qGjdvX0e6QTI1dT9qdr
encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
Duration: 00:00:10.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16952 kb/s
Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1080x1920, 16948 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Input #1, mp3, from 'Knockout.mp3':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf61.5.101
Duration: 00:02:14.54, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 131 kb/s
Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3 (mp3float), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc61.12
[fc#0 @ 0000025538b16280] Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:a]volume=0.1,atempo=1.1[a];[1:a]volume=1[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2[audio] matches no streams.
Error binding filtergraph inputs/outputs: Invalid argument
